# jQuery mobile fixed footer not hiding

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QyeMv/)

The footer is set with `data-position="fixed"` but tapping the screen will not hide the footer element as shown [here in the jquery mobile fixed toolbars example](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html). Anyone knows why?

The footer is getting the class `.ui-fixed-hidden` but nothing happens, I guess some js rows is not kicking in.

Comment: Why do you think that tapping the screen should hide your fixed footer?

Comment: because if you follow the link above to the jquery mobile example you will see that it hides on click. Also in the jsfiddle the footer gets the class "ui-fixed-hidden" when clicking the body.

Comment: It's because you don't have enough content on the page so there is no reason for the footer to hide. If you look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7ws3X/1/ you will see the footer hide.

Comment: make that an answer @codemonkey and you will get the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footer is not hidden because there is not enough content on the page. It will only hide if it is obscuring content so that you can see the content.

If you add enough content to the page to scroll past the end the footer will hide on tap.